# Why do we feel cold in the lower part when we lie down?

Tags: human-biology, physiology

This question is based on my personal experience. But I believe that this common for many of us.

Let us say that I am sitting on a chair in normal indoor dress. Then, if I lie down on bed, I will feel the need to cover the lower portion of my body.

As I have seen at home, I am working sitting on a chair. Then I lie down in the same dress, and i feel the need to cover my lower part. When traveling in some sleeper train, people ask for blankets when they lie down, not while they are sitting. It is not that they change their dresses when they lie down, they are in the same dress.

Why does this happen? Why do we feel colder, specially in the lower portion, when we lie down?

Comment: Could you clarify whether it's just sensation of cold or does the feet actually get cold? Please touch the feet whether when you are feeling cold, if they are warm to touch them it may be peripheral neuropathy.  Atlast welcome to biology.se

Comment: @JM97 It's just sensation of cold. My feet are perfectly warm.

Comment: Then it may be due to peripheral neuropathy? It's my opinion , please consult a doctor.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused please don't use the term "everyone". A), you don't know that, and B), it's not true.

Comment: @MattDMo Thanks for your correction. so, the corrected comment would be, it is a widespread phenomenon, many people do this (including me, Doraemon and Nobita for say :P ), but for me it seems to be not exactly "feeling *extra* cold" but a complicated psychological need ("wish" to to get covered).